# "no such table" error with in-memory database

Tags: sqlite, go

I am using an in-memory SQLite database:

```
func init() {
    global.ConductorConfig = readConfig()
    log.Println(utils.GetCurrentDir() + global.ConductorConfig.DbFile)
    //db = sqlx.MustConnect("sqlite3", utils.GetCurrentDir()+global.ConductorConfig.DbFile)
    db = sqlx.MustConnect("sqlite3", ":memory:")
    db.Exec(schema)
    task:=model.Task{}
    SaveTask(&task)
    db.MapperFunc(func(s string) string {
        return s
    })
}
```

In my `main` func I create the table:

```
if global.ConductorConfig.DevMode {
    db.CreateTables()
}
go job.HeartbeatJob()
go job.TaskClearJob()
app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {
    ListenAndServe()
    return nil
}
```

I get "no such table" in HTTP handler function:

```
existed, err := db.GetAgentByServerName(agent.ServerName)
if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    log.Println("[conductor] error occurred when get agent by server name: " + err.Error())
    return err
}

func GetAgentByServerName(name string) (*model.Agent, error) {
    agent := &model.Agent{}
    err := db.Get(agent, "select * from agent where ServerName=$1", name)

    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        err = nil
        agent = nil
    }

    return agent, err
}
```

When I start the program I got:

> error occurred when get agent by server name: no such table: agent

Database schema (attributes omitted):

```
var schema = `
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS agent;
CREATE TABLE agent (
    Id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS task;
CREATE TABLE task (
    Id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

Minimal example to reproduce the error.

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
        _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
        "log"
    )
    
    var db *sqlx.DB
    
    func init() {
        db = sqlx.MustConnect("sqlite3", ":memory:")
        db.Exec("CREATE TABLE agent (Id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,);")
    }
    
    func main()  {
        _, err:=db.Exec("insert into agent values (1)")
        if err!=nil{
            log.Println(err)
        }

}
```

Comment: You create an [in-memory](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) sqlite database with the special ":memory:" filename... looks like you're using a normal file based database.

Comment: And are you sure that your `db.CreateTables()` function is getting called? What is that function, anyways? It sounds important but you don't show the source...

Comment: where is the statement that you’re already selecting the right database...?

Comment: @Shawn Sorry, I just update my code. db.CreateTables() is called because it works in the file base sqlite

Comment: @FendiD I don't quite follow you. do you mean something like 'use database xxxx'? I don't use such and it works with a file based memory.

Comment: That table definition doesn't have a ServerName column... and you really should confirm that that CreateTables() function is getting called and actually creating tables, because it sure doesn't look like it is or the error would be about an unknown column.

Comment: @Shawn It has. I omit it because there are too many attributes.

Comment: If you can't show your actual code or a minimal complete example that demonstrates the problem it makes helping so much harder.

Comment: @Shawn I can't share actual code but I do have a minimal example here

Comment: @Shawn I've updated the question, thanks for your help

Comment: oh... my bad.. i tho its like using regular databases...

Comment: Your new example program has a syntax error in the create table statement (The ones in that schema string do too now that I look at it more). Always check to see if functions return errors...

Answer (score 5):

`:memory:` will **open a separate database for each connection**. use `file::memory:?cache=shared` instead.

Update: I also run into some lock issues using the above code, it seems to me that use `:memory:` with `db.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(1)` in tests is a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Maybe this would help someone**

I had the same issue with 'no such table' and found an exact explanation:

*If sql.Rows is not closed before next query then driver returns no such table on next query. Issue exists only for in-memory storage, same test for file backed db runs fine.*

After that, I found the part of code where I had forgotten to do `rows.Close()`, fixed that and now it works with no issues.

Original answer: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/511#issuecomment-396290916

Answer (score 1):

If you used the same schema for creating table the one you posted here then the table is never created because the schema has syntax error and it should be like this

```
var schema = `
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS agent;
  CREATE TABLE agent (
    Id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
 );

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS task;
  CREATE TABLE task (
    Id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
`
```

And I'm guessing your code is same as example code, so in the init function you have skipped the error checking for `db.Exec(schema)` (which you should never do that for any function in `Go`). As the error is not checked and it got an error for executing the schema so the tables are never created but the program continues, correct your schema and check the error then try it again. 
Try this in you init function:

```
_, err := db.Exec(schema)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: I missed ` in the post but not in the code, otherwise it will not even compile.

Comment: The back tick is not the issue you need to remove the comma `,` after the PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0):

I have "“no such table” error with in-memory sqlite" occurred when I tried to use transactions with error. Example:

```
tx, err = DB.Begin()
if err != nil {
    ErrorStatus = true
    goto ErrorLabel
}
tempQuery = "INSERT INTO msg_to_like (msg_id, user_id) " +
    "VALUES ('" + nmbr + "', " + usr + ");"
fmt.Println(tempQuery)
if _, err = DB.Exec(tempQuery); err != nil {
    ErrorStatus = true
    goto ErrorLabel
}
...
```

But was necessary:

```
if _, err = tx.Exec(tempQuery); err != nil {
```

After this error, the used tables was crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because of a programming mistake, in one line I referenced the `tx` transaction, in a different line I referenced `r.db`:

wrong:

```golang
err = r.db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
result := tx.Where(...
...
result = r.db.Create
return nil
})
```

correct:

```golang
err = r.db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
result := tx.Where(...
...
result = tx.Create
return nil
})
```